# Sell Software Online using Third Party

Tags: e-commerce

**Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409026/software-marketplace**

I'm interested in selling software (mostly enterprisey libraries) online but I'm not interested in handling the money/shopping cart/etc so I'm on the lookout for a third party that can handle all my payments/downloads for a fee (a bit like Google Ads, but for software instead of advertisement).

The ideal scenario would be that I just had to upload the file(s) to their server, set a price on each file and link to an address from my own site.

Anyone got any experience with these things? Any provider you can recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software marketplace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409026/software-marketplace)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used them, but I believe [ComponentSource](http://www.componentsource.com) is a software reseller.  Here's their publisher program information page:
http://www.componentsource.com/services/publisher/software-reseller.html